# Bash: Is it possible to change command before execution

Tags: bash, terminal, command-line-arguments, bsd, getopt

I want to change the command so that command line flag(options) are placed before command line arguments, as which is done automatically by GNU getopt.

Mac use BSD getopt so that function is lacked. I want to tweak the bash so that upon executing of one command, I run a script that parse the flags and arguments reorder them and execute the reordered command.

In this way, both

```
ls -lh /tmp
ls /tmp -lh
```

will work in my Mac's terminal.

Comment: what kind of order changing do you assume on case of 3 or more options `cp -R /root /bkp` for example

Comment: Now that I think about it, do you know you can get a lot of the GNU tools on your Mac via the coreutils macport http://www.macports.org/ports.php?by=name&substr=coreutils (and probably others)? Maybe this could help you in your endeavor.

Comment: @Mat, I think replacing them is tedious and dangerous. Besides, it won't work with other executables that depend on BSD getopt. I was considering building a shell that do the reorder and then call bash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't safely write a general purpose tool to do the job of reordering arguments on a command line unless you know what the `optstring` argument to the `getopt()` function looks like for each command.  Consider:

```
make something -f makefile
cp   something -f makefile
```

In the first command, you have to move both the `-f` and `makefile` to the front to canonicalize the command invocation. In the second, you must only move the `-f`; if you move the following file name too, you rewrite the command and destroy your data.

Of course, you also have to know what the `getopt_long()` argument strings look like if the command takes long-form `--force` or `--file=makefile` style arguments too.

Frankly, you'd do better to use POSIXLY_CORRECT in your environment on Linux and forget about the insidious flexibility it provides, and learn to write your options before your arguments at all times.  Your code will work across all Unix-like machines better if you do that.

---

You could install GNU software in some directory other than `/bin` and `/usr/bin` (e.g. `/usr/gnu/bin` and then ensure that you place `/usr/gnu/bin` on your PATH ahead of the system directories.  There are pre-built systems like [`fink`](http://www.finkproject.org/), too. However, that won't help with tools from Apple that don't have analogues from GNU.  And there's a 'danger' that shell scripts you write will not be portable to other Macs that don't have the same setup that you do.